# Sending and receiving multiple variables using MVVM Light Messager

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

What is the proper way to send and receive multiple variables using MVVM Light Messanger?

In the following code I send `17 for Age` and `100 for Amount` but I receive 0 for Age and 100 for Amount.

**Output:**

> 17
>   0
>   0
>   100

What am I missing?

Do I need to use a different model for each variable that I need to send?

**XAML:**

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Send Message" Command="{Binding SendMessageCommand}"/>
```

**Codebehind:**

```
namespace MvvmLightMessager
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Messenger.Default.Register<MyMessage>(this, m => ReceivedMessageFromMyViewModel(m));
            Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();
        }

        private void ReceivedMessageFromMyViewModel(MyMessage m)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Age);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Amount);
            // Output
            // 17
            // 0
            // 0
            // 100
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
namespace MvvmLightMessager.Model
{
    class MyMessage
    {
        public double Age { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
namespace MvvmLightMessager.ViewModel
{ 
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public RelayCommand SendMessageCommand { get; private set; } 
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            SendMessageCommand = new RelayCommand(() => SendMessage());
        }

        private void SendMessage()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send<MyMessage>(new MyMessage { Age = 17 });
            Messenger.Default.Send<MyMessage>(new MyMessage { Amount = 1000 });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your expectation? You send 2 messages separately. First one, ``{Age 17, Amount 0}`` and ``{Age 0, Amount 100}``. So, the output prints 2 times with Age 17, Amount 0, Age 0 Amount 100. It's completely normal...

Comment: Oh I see, they should be send like so... `Messenger.Default.Send<MyMessage>(new MyMessage { Age = 17 , Amount = 100});` thanks!

Comment: I write down the answer for the others.

Answer (score 0):

You send 2 messages separately. First one, `{Age 17, Amount 0}` and `{Age 0, Amount 100}`. So, the output prints 2 times with 2 records `Age 17, Amount 0` and  `Age 0 Amount 100`. It's completely normal